# how to get the next line after if in python

Tags: python

Hello I have a file like this:

```
A.
B.
C.
D.
E.
A.
D.
A.
F.
S.
```

I'd like to print the lines immediately after `A`.

[image]

Comment: `print('B.')` doesn't work?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We are not a homework service; please see [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for why this is not a good question. If this is in fact homework, [consider giving this a read too](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions).

Comment: @lxop i want b, d, f according this file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
with open("./f") as f:
  read_next = False
  for line in f:
    if line.strip() == 'A.':
      read_next = True
      continue

    if read_next:
      read_next = False
      print line
```

Where the file `./f` contains:

```
A.
B.
C.
D.
E.
A.
D.
A.
F.
S.
```

And this outputs:

```
B.

D.

F.
```

A simpler method that requires reading all of the data into memory is this:

```
with open("./f") as f:
  lines = f.read().splitlines()
  for i,line in enumerate(lines):
    if line == 'A.' and i < (len(lines)-1):
      print lines[i+1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions get the job done.

```
import re

your_file = open("your_file", "r")
content = your_file.read()
your_file.close()

# Looks for "A.\n" and grabs the character and period after it.
matches = re.search("A\.\n([A-Z]\.)", content)
```

[Demo to see that it works.](https://pythex.org/?regex=A%5C.%5Cn(%5BA-Z%5D%5C.)&test_string=A.%0AB.%0AC.%0AD.%0AE.%0AA.%0AD.%0AA.%0AF.%0AS.&ignorecase=0&multiline=0&dotall=0&verbose=0)